# Unique user id in multi tenant Azure AD apps

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, azure-ad-graph-api

Do you know the **unique user id** in multi tenant Azure AD apps pattern?

I'm now developing app using [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph) with Azure AD [multi-tenant application pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview). For identifying each user I want to know the unique id - I'll use it as a key in our own database to save user's data.

In this [reference](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user#properties), id parameter in user object is "The unique identifier for the user", but I wonder **is it unique id in each tenant or in all tenant**? It is important thing because my app will use in multi tenant.

FYI:
If user id is unique only in each tenant, I'll concatenate [organization id](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/organization#properties) and user id for making unique id in all tenant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id property is a random GUID. While it would be unlikely to have two users with identical IDs, unless there is a check in Azure, it could happen.

I would concatenate it with the tenant ID, or even better have the tenant ID in another column in the DB. That way you can query users on a per-tenant basis in your DB.

Comment: In general, you should be able to treat the id property as unique across the directory.  Also you might be interested in a new feature we just released that allows you to extend existing resource types with your own application data.  Check out https://dev.office.com/blogs/adding-customer-data-to-resources-in-Microsoft-Graph-preview.

Comment: @RasmusW thanks for your answer. I'll utilize this DB scheme and store user data :)

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT
Thanks for your quick comment! Let me confirm one point. Does "across the directory" means **in all directory**? If it is true, I'll treat the user id as unique id in all company.
And I'm interested in your suggestion.I'll check new feature with my team.

Comment: Yes - entire cloud directory, across all tenants.

Comment: Thanks @DanKershaw-MSFT! I can decided to use it as unique key :)