# Azure AD Group ID uniqueness

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Piggy backing off this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42747115/unique-user-id-in-multi-tenant-azure-ad-apps/74337480#74337480). Is it a safe assumption that group ids GUIDs are unique throughout the whole Azure AD directory? Or are they just guaranteed unique within tenants?

Specifically talking about the Group Resource type ID from the: [Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/group?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Answer (score 1):

Yes , group ids are unique throughout the whole Azure AD directory.

Hope your doubt is clear now.

Thanks